# Identification de propos dans une vidéo (d'Élie Yaffa du 10 janvier 2019) ?

Tags: oral, grossieretes

Dans [une](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5315) [vidéo](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bsd796Ogyg-) un rappeur en invite un autre à un combat<sup>1</sup> :

> Armand, tu vas recevoir demain le contrat par huissier, signé par
>   moi-même, à Universal, comme t'as demandé à l'attention de [nom de l'adversaire]
>   [**(1) t'sais que... premier à flauber...?**] T'es pas dans le top. T'es une grosse merde ! T'es un [**(2)...?**].
>   Ta seule issue, c'est la bagarre. [...]
>
> [ Retranscription des propos de Élie Yaffa sur son compte de réseau
>   social ]

---

- Peut-on retranscrire la phrase en (1) et identifier le nom ou l'adjectif en (2) ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Je m'intéresse généralement aux arts martiaux et aux techniques de combat mais je n'aime pas du tout la théâtralité violente du milieu de la musique (rap) ni l'atteinte à la propriété etc. et ne souhaite certainement pas en faire la promotion ici ni cautionner aucun des propos actuels ou passés de la personne citée. Je veux simplement comprendre ce qu'on dit.</sub>

Comment: Nota Bene, en France personne sait qui est Elie Yaffa, tout le monde l'appelle Booba. Pareil pour tous les autres rappeurs.

Comment: @NinoFiliu Merci, je comprends. J'évite le _click bait_ et ne me sens lié que par l'état civil. En ce qui me concerne je ne connais aucun de ces musiciens et ne m'y intéresse pas particulièrement, j'utilise tous les contextes comme de simples occasions de poser des questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Tu sais que ton album il va flopper (il va [faire un flop](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_un_flop))

2: T'es en [hess](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hess) (t'es en galère, tu as du souci à te faire)

Comment: Merci, j'entendais sss mais je ne pouvais identifier ça....